# BQ Aquaris M10 FHD Ubuntu Edition: How do I see the size of external storage (ie. a micro SD card)?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, aquaris, bq, m10

I have had a look in the file browser app and the External Drives app, long-pressing various items in both apps, and looking for any "menu" items in both of these apps, but I haven't found how to see the size of the card.

In Ubuntu 16.04 (on my desktop computer), for example, I can start the **Disks** utility (actually an application called `gnome-disks`, and not `gnome-disk-utility` as shown **Disks** > **Menu** > **About**) and see total size and % used for each storage unit (SSD, HDD, and external drives).

I can also see a drive's total space and free space from within **Files** (actually `nautilus`).

How do I do it on this tablet?

Comment: There's an app called "ciborium" that I thought was installed by default that shows disk space options. I'm not sure how it's named from a user perspective, I'll have to check once I get my m10 back up and running...

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid that I don't have an SD card to hand and so can't test my M10 using Nautilus.

Have you installed any software on your M10? I just checked and I could install gnome-disk-utility. That might be your best bet since you are already comfortable using it.

To install it you will first need to create a container. If you haven't done this before it's best to do it by ssh'ing into the machine [see answer here for and explanation].

This container will be called '4installs'.

```
libertine-container-manager create -i 4installs
```

To install the application:

```
libertine-container-manager install-package -p gnome-disk-utility -i 4installs
```

Now Disks will be available to use.

Alternatively you can check this info in the Terminal app:

```
df -h
```

will list all the filesystem partitions, their size and available space and where they are mounted.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Jack. I am trying to avoid installing software into this tablet via creating containers, so that: (a) the OTA update process continues to work; and (b) I am able to give useful feedback to Canonical and BQ Support regarding the OS and device.

If it becomes inevitable, I would start by using the terminal, but I'm also trying to avoid using the terminal on this device, for the reason described at (b) above.

I believe the functionality I require is a basic necessity.

Comment: Creating containers doesn't cause any problems with OTA updates. It did in the past but this issue has been addressed since OTA 11 as far as I remember.

For what it's worth I think you are correct that what you are looking for should be basic functionality.

Not a lot of people seem to look at ubuntu-touch questions here. It might be worth posting a link to the ubuntu-touch email list. I'll post to the ubuntu-touch Freenode channel now.

Comment: OK that's news to me about the containers and OTA updates. That seems like a big deal, so I'm surprised that known/registered owners of Ubuntu Touch devices weren't advised.

I sent an email about this exact same issue to ubuntu-tablet@lists.launchpad.net on 1 March 2017.

Comment: Is that an active list? The archives don't seem very up to date: https://lists.launchpad.net/ubuntu-tablet/ You might get a better response on https://lists.launchpad.net/ubuntu-phone/

Comment: I have no idea whether it's active or not. I'll send the same email to ubuntu-phone@lists.launchpad.net as well - thanks.

Comment: PS I also sent it to ubuntu-touch-coreapps@lists.launchpad.net.

Comment: I didn't get a response from any of those emails.

I just got a chance to try installing packages in containers. As usual, I want to install `vlc` and `chromium-browser`. I created the container without incident, but when I tried to install either package, I get the same result (example copied from when I tried to install `chromium-browser`):

https://pastebin.com/GwhEcSQR

PS: Note that I deliberately have the system language set to Spanish.

Comment: After my last comment, I restarted the tablet, and ran the command `libertine-container-manager install-package -p chromium-browser -i greg` again. So far, so good. It's downloading tons of stuff (updates, files, and applications).

Comment: Oh dear. The command 'libertine-container-manager install-package -p chromium-browser -i greg' went swimmingly for a long time, but then sat there at 11% whilst "unpacking" files. I tried to uninstall `chromium-browser`, and then spend an hour or so to reinstall it, but: https://pastebin.com/s3gs6YMA I'm just restarting the tablet now so that I can try it again.

Comment: No, that didn't work. I'll leave `chromium-browser` for the minute, and try to install `vlc`.

Comment: No, installing `vlc` didn't work either. It seemed to get started OK, but came up against a couple of errors during the installation process after looking in the repositories again: https://pastebin.com/5bBQJCRz

Comment: I just destroyed the container:  `libertine-container-manager destroy -i greg`. I'll restart, and start again from the beginning.